# How do I set up how often control tasks are shown to a toloker?

Tags: toloka

When I set up a page with the tasks, I want to make sure that a performer completes at least 1 control task per page so that I can check his quality in real time. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

When you upload your file with Smart Mixing, you can indicate the number of control tasks per page.